# aplicar evento a um input com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom, preciso aplicar o evento `$(".margem").keyup();` apenas nos input que contenha um valor maior que 0.

Reparem que ao alterar o valor do custo o sistema aplica o evento `$(".margem").keyup();` atualizando o input `valor`, porém o segundo input valor não contem uma margem e por isso ele não pode ser atualizando.

Alguém sabe como fazer essa verificação?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Verifica se o custo mudou
  $(".custo").on("keyup", function() {
    $(".margem").keyup();
  });


  // Faz o calculo do valor com base na margem
  $(".margem").on("keyup", function() {

    // Margem
    var margem = $(this).val();
    var custo = $('#custo').val();

    // Formata valor para pt-br
    calculo = margem + custo;

    // Atualiza input
    var inputValor = $(this).attr("valor");
    $("#" + inputValor).val(calculo).trigger('blur');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
custo:
<input type='text' class='custo' id='custo' name='custo' value='8'>

<br>
<br>
<br> Valor X Margem<br>
<input type='text' class='valor valores' id='valor1' name='valor1' margem='margem1'>
<input type='text' class='margem lucro' id='margem1' name='margem1' valor='valor1' value='1'>

<br>
<br>
<br> Valor X Margem<br>
<input type='text' class='valor valores' id='valor2' name='valor2' margem='margem2'>
<input type='text' class='margem lucro' id='margem2' name='margem2' valor='valor2'>
```

Comment: Na bem da verdade, você não precisa verificar se o valor é maior que zero no Javascript. Muda o "type" do seu input para "number" e adiciona a propriedade `min = '1'` no mesmo. Mas se você quiser usar mesmo um código pra verificar, usa a função que o @Mathias escreveu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hugo, o código abaixo percorre todos os elementos que possuem a classe `.margem` e verifica se o elemento possui um `val()`, se possuir ele aplica o evento `keyup()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Verifica se o custo mudou
  $(".custo").on("keyup", function() {
    $('.margem').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val()) {
        if (parseInt($(this).val()) > 0)
          $(this).keyup();
      }
    });
    //$(".margem").keyup();
  });


  // Faz o calculo do valor com base na margem
  $(".margem").on("keyup", function() {
    if ($(this).val() > 0) {
      // Margem
      var margem = $(this).val();
      var custo = $('#custo').val();

      // Formata valor para pt-br
      calculo = margem + custo;

      // Atualiza input
      var inputValor = $(this).attr("valor");
      $("#" + inputValor).val(calculo).trigger('blur');
    } else {
      var inputValor = $(this).attr("valor");
      $("#" + inputValor).val("").trigger('blur');
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
custo:
<input type='text' class='custo' id='custo' name='custo' value='8'>

<br>
<br>
<br> Valor X Margem<br>
<input type='text' class='valor valores' id='valor1' name='valor1' margem='margem1'>
<input type='text' class='margem lucro' id='margem1' name='margem1' valor='valor1' value='1'>

<br>
<br>
<br> Valor X Margem<br>
<input type='text' class='valor valores' id='valor2' name='valor2' margem='margem2'>
<input type='text' class='margem lucro' id='margem2' name='margem2' valor='valor2'>
```

Comment: testei aqui, e quase isso. so tem um problema quando o input margem esta com valor 0 ele aplica o evento, o quero tem que verificar se o valor do input esta em branco e se é maior que 0.

Comment: @HugoBorges ok, corrigido, nota que se tu limpar a margem agora, o valor do input também será limpo.

Comment: perfeito, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a solução mais simples é simplesmente retornar caso não tenha valor:

```js
$(".custo").on("keyup", function() {
$(".margem").keyup();
});

    $(".margem").on("keyup", function() {
     
        // Margem
        var margem = $(this).val();

        // (!margem) funciona tanto para 0 como para "", pois ambos resultam false na condição
        if(!margem) return;

     var custo = $('#custo').val();
     
     // Formata valor para pt-br
     calculo = parseInt(margem) + parseInt(custo);
     
        // Atualiza input
        var inputValor = $(this).attr("valor");
        $("#" + inputValor).val(calculo).trigger('blur');
        
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
custo:
<input type='text' class='custo' id='custo' name='custo' value='8'>

<br>
<br>
<br> Valor X Margem<br>
<input type='text' class='valor valores' id='valor1' name='valor1' margem='margem1'>
<input type='text' class='margem lucro' id='margem1' name='margem1' valor='valor1' value='1'>

<br>
<br>
<br> Valor X Margem<br>
<input type='text' class='valor valores' id='valor2' name='valor2' margem='margem2'>
<input type='text' class='margem lucro' id='margem2' name='margem2' valor='valor2'>
```

Além do mais, seu código está concatenando os valores na soma, então sugiro que (caso queira somar, como eu suspeito), troque a seguinte linha:

```
calculo = margem + custo;
```

para:

```
calculo = parseInt(margem) + parseInt(custo);
```